# Java program hangs when executed when it didn't before

Tags: java, jvm

When I run this program it hangs, is it something to do with the code? Because if it is, I can't spot the bug.

```
public class PalindromeSolution {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String [] arr;
        String s1 = "taco cat";
        boolean palindrome = true;

        s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        arr = s1.split("(?!^)");

        int i = 0;
        while(i < arr.length) {
            if(arr[i] == arr[(arr.length - 1) - i]) {
                i++;
            } else {
                palindrome = false;
                break;
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("Is palindrome: " + palindrome);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running it? In an IDE with a breakpoint, perhaps?

Comment: Code runs just fine.

Comment: @Andreas I was using a text mate and I ran it using the terminal. Couple of people said it's running fine for them. So perhaps it is an issue with my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't hang for me. But it's incorrect,
because you shouldn't compare strings with `==`,
you should use `.equals()`.
With this change it will run correctly:

```
    if(arr[i].equals(arr[(arr.length - 1) - i])) {
```

... though poorly:

- Why split to strings? Better use `s1.toCharArray()`
- Why iterate until `arr.length`? `arr.length / 2` would be enough
- A `for` loop is more natural for this than a `while` loop

Like this:

```
    String s1 = "taco cat";
    boolean palindrome = true;

    s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    char[] arr = s1.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[(arr.length - 1) - i]) {
            palindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Is palindrome: " + palindrome);
```

Comment: cheers. The reason I split the strings is because I wanted to do it in the most basic form as possible but I also didn't have knowledge of the toCharArray() method. I noticed that I could have iterated to only half the length of the array when I was dry running the code, but I wasn't to sure if it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuffer in order to keep keep your code simple:

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
StringBuffer str2=new StringBuffer(s1);
str2.reverse();
if(str2.toString().equals(s1))
     return true;
else 
     return false
```